# paytm checksum locally works fine, but on server(Heroku) it gives invalid checksum error

Tags: java, spring-boot, checksum, paytm

My Paytm Checksum Generation code:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/pgredirect", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
        public String getRedirect(@RequestBody Paytm paytm) throws Exception {
    //paytm include( MID,WEBSITE,INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID,CHANNEL_ID,ORDER_ID, CUST_ID,MOBILE_NO,EMAIL,TXN_AMOUNT,CALLBACK_URL) fields

        TreeMap<String, String> paytmParams = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        paytmDetails.getDetails().forEach((k, v) -> paytmParams.put(k, v));


        paytmParams.put("MOBILE_NO", paytm.getMOBILE_NO());
        paytmParams.put("EMAIL", paytm.getEMAIL());
        paytmParams.put("ORDER_ID", paytm.getORDER_ID());
        paytmParams.put("TXN_AMOUNT", paytm.getTXN_AMOUNT());
        paytmParams.put("CUST_ID", paytm.getCUST_ID());


        String checksum = CheckSumServiceHelper.getCheckSumServiceHelper().genrateCheckSum(env.getProperty("merchantKey"),
                paytmParams);
        paytmParams.put("CHECKSUMHASH", checksum);

        //return checksum;
        return checksum;

    }
```

When I run the code on localhost:4200(Angular) and localhost:8080 (spring boot) it works fine, but when I deploy the same code on **Heroku** cloud, it gives me an invalid checksum error. Is there any problem with checksum creation?

Answer (score 0):

Please cross-check your server's configuration with your local server, in case the issue still persists please use Paytm's latest jar for creating checksum - https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_JAVA_Checksum